"vault" secret resolver fail to fetch secret and return dial tcp i/o timeout despite that the url is reached from network
I hav a gitlab job that fetched secret from vault. but when runner try to fetch secret using vault secret resolver i got an error : ERROR: Job failed (system failure): resolving secrets: initializing Vault service: preparing authenticated client: checking Vault server health: Get "https://xxxxxxxxx.com:2800": dial tcp x.x.x.x:8200: i/o timeout
But when i do a curl https://xxxxxxxxx.com:2800 from runner to the url i got HTTP 200.
Can any one help me to know the issue cause.
I tried all possible config but no success
